# React Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm using react with typescript and was getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error when return `language.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory)` so I added a checking as in below. Error is gone but I'm not sure whether It can impact the performance. Please advice.

```
import { filter } from 'lodash';
...
return filter(channels, ({
    language
}: Channels) => {
    if (
        language &&
        language.toLowerCase() !== selectedCategory &&
        selectedCategory !== 'all'
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return (
        language && language.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory)
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead.

If the language is not null or undefined (nullish) it will access the property or method you want otherwise it will return undefined

Answer (score 1):

No, that will not impact performance in any way, that's an incredibly inexpensive and common type of check to performance.

You can simplify it though with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

If you write `language?.toLowercase()`, it will evaluate to `undefined` if language is undefined, and a lowercase language if it is defined. So:

```js
if (
        language?.toLowerCase() !== selectedCategory &&
        selectedCategory !== 'all'
    ) {
        return false;
    } else { 
       return language?.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory)
    }
```

Comment: In the second line, you misplaced the `?`

Comment: I actually misplaced it on the first line, good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're damn sure about `language` that it can't be `null` or `undefined` then use [`!` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (**non-null assertion operator**) and rewrite your code like this:

```
import { filter } from 'lodash';
...
return filter(channels, ({
    language
}: Channels) => {
    return language!.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory);
});
```

Or You can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the object value is never null or undefined, You can use `!` mark:

```
language!.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that `language` will never be undefined, you can use the `!` [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#:%7E:text=Non%2Dnull%20assertion%20operator&text=produces%20a%20value%20of%20the,in%20the%20emitted%20JavaScript%20code.) to remove that warning.

```
language!.toLowerCase()
```

This is the best option in terms of runtime performance since when the code is transpiled into JavaScript the assertion operator is just removed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. It's possible it'll lead to a slight performance benefit in older browsers (see [here](https://blog.allegro.tech/2019/11/performance-of-javascript-optional-chaining.html)), but optional chaining realistically is *never* going to be a performance bottlneck. Working with the compiler instead of against it, and getting type safety, is much more important in practice.